# Multiple handler after camels onException

Tags: java, exception, apache-camel

I'm fairly new to apache camel, but I want to build an exception handling using `onException`.
Since I want to catch the exception and provide a response, but also want to log the error to an external system, I'd like to have 2 beans to handle the exception.

Currrently I'm having

```
onException(Exception.class)
       .handled(true)
       .bean(MyExceptionHandler.class);
```

I'd like to have

```
onException(Exception.class)
       .handled(true)
       .bean(MyExceptionHandler.class)
       .bean(MyExceptionLogger.class)
```

However, the `MyExceptionLogger` is never called, since the handling seems to be done after the `MyExceptionHandler`.

What can I do about this? Apart from putting the logging logic into the `MyExceptionHandler` because I'd like to seperate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what you are doing inside `MyExceptionHandler.class` but this should simply work. You can add as much steps to the Exception handler as you like. It is basically a normal Camel route.

However, I can imagine that **when an Exception occurs** in `MyExceptionHandler.class` that the message simply "disappears" without touching `MyExceptionLogger.class`.

Comment: Basically I add a fault to the `exchange.getOut()` using `exchange.getOut().setFault(true)` and `exchange.getOut().setBody(serviceFault)` Maybe this somehow closes the route?

Comment: Ah, the fault flag in Camel represents an irrecoverable error. I have no idea how this behaves if you set this flag in the error handling. Another point: you are working with the out message. This is for most of all cases not recommended. Camel copies over all aspects of the in message to the out message, all for free and invisible for you, **as long as the out message is not touched**. Conclusion: manipulate the in message instead of out and try if not setting the fault flag helps for your concrete problem

Comment: Ok, this helps me a lot to understand my problem. Thank you